# HttpSendRequest() functions fails after two request and returns after timeout, how to deal

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to download same files with different ranges at a time via multiple threads( >2 )

But among all these threads, any two threads are successfully passes `HttpSendRequest(`) function and in remaining threads `HttpSendRequest()` fails after timeout with `GetLastError()` code of 0.

Is `HttpSendRequest()` only allow to send 2 request or is their any other way to handle this situation??

Answer (score 0):

HTTP allowed maximum two connection. to increase connections you can use [Option Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wininet/option-flags) to with InternetSetOption() function.

You will find code in [this](https://microsoft.public.vc.mfc.narkive.com/GHHEnJ7P/how-maximun-connect-that-wininet-library-support-to-connect-to-server-at-the-same-time) link.